# How can you put variables inside laravel 4's HTML::image and HTML::image elements?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Say I have this line of code including an image:

```
{{ HTML::image('folder/templates_folder/light_template/image.png') }}
```

I want to include a bunch of of other images that use the same directory so I'd like to store part of the path as a variable...

Is there a way I can put a variable inside like this:

```
{{HTML::image('{{$imagePath}}/image.png')}}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks. I'd like to do the same for the HTML::style element, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need brackets in there any more, they already surrond the whole block. You can do this like this:

```
{{HTML::image($imagePath.'/' .$image . '.png')}}
```

If you have different file extensions, you can simply change this to a variable, too.

```
{{HTML::image($imagePath.'/' .$image . '.' . $extension)}}
```